# Can I loop through each page (1 to 100 pages) for multiple URL's (905 websites) in R?

Tags: r, rvest, scrape

I scraped multiple urls using the below code:

```
x <- NULL
for (i in 1:5){
  k1<-"https://forums.vwvortex.com/forumdisplay.php?5449-Atlas-SUV/page"
  k2<-"&pp=200"
  url<-paste(k1,i,k2,sep="") 
  review <- read_html(url)
  threads<- cbind(review %>% html_nodes("h3.threadtitle") %>% html_nodes("a") %>%   html_attr("href")  )
 x<- rbind(x, threads)}

x[] <- Map(paste, 'https://forums.vwvortex.com/', x, sep="")
url<- paste(x)
url <- sub("\\&s=bd72f867af71d9d03d74dc394a45b624","/page", url)
```

Now, I have all the required urls. I am also able to scrape all the replies associated with each url I scraped previously using the following code:

```
results <- lapply(url, function(i) {
  review <- read_html(i)
  threads<- cbind(review %>% html_nodes("blockquote.postcontent.restore") %>% html_text())
  replies <- as.data.frame(threads)
  return(replies)   
})
```

Problem is that I am able to scrape only first page of each URL. Is there a way that I will be able to loop through 1 to 100 pages for each url I scraped?

Comment: What error are you having exactly?

Comment: @Stedy I do not have an error. I need help to write a code which scrapes all the pages within each URL.

Comment: This is not a code writing service, you will have better luck getting help if you can format your question to an [mcve]

Comment: @Stedy I understand what your saying. I just needed some help with adding a loop inside lapply function or something like that. Here is the one I tried to get all pages for each url:-   url <-  foreach (i= 1:100) %do% paste(url, i , sep = "") . url here has 905 websites but this code loops only the first url in the data frame.